# asp.net core validation after filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to run some custom logic for all APIs (asp.net core) that we have in our service before model validation but after model binding. Is this possible? I tried an ActionFilter but it gets called after validation. Resource filter also does not work for us. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you want to run before model validation? Model validation is part of model binding.

Comment: @Nairooz - did my answer below solve your issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Web API controllers don't have to check ModelState.IsVali](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2)d if they have the [ApiController] attribute. In that case, an automatic HTTP 400 response containing issue details is returned when model state is invalid.

One way to achieve what you want is to suppress this behavior.

Add the following code to ConfigureServices:

```
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        });
```

Then you can add your code to the filter - eg:

```
public class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // do something before the action executes
        if(context.ActionArguments != null && context.ActionArguments.Count > 0)
        {
            //WARNING - you should add "safe" code to access the dictionary
            //I have hardcoded the parameter name (data) here for sample only.
            var model = context.ActionArguments["data"];
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // do something after the action executes
    }
}
```

of course you need to apply the filter as well - in the example case below, I have applied it globally. You can be more specific if you want.

```
services.AddMvc(
            options => options.Filters.Add(new SampleActionFilter())
            ).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

In your controller code, you can also further use the TryValidateModel method if you want, like so:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProcessController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Contact(FormDataModel data)
    {
        bool validated = TryValidateModel(data);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Id cannot be empty..");
            return Ok();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem.