# How to add Error or response Code in the API response in .Net 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a POST method in .Net 5 API. I have added `ValidationAttribute` (by inheriting from it) on some properties on the request class.

It's working as expected, But I want to add a response code along with the error message. But there is no method or properties for error or response code in `ValidationAttribute`.

So is there any way to do this?

I have tried to add the response code in this way, but this code doesn't get called itself.

```
services.AddScoped<RequestModelValidationAttribute>(); //Code for dependency  injection

public class RequestModelValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    ResponseModel<ResponseAPI> apiResponse = new ResponseModel<ResponseAPI>
    {
        ResponseCode = "01",
        ResponseMessage = "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// OnActionExecuting
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var modelState in context.ModelState)
            {
                if (modelState.Value.ValidationState == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Invalid)
                {
                    switch (modelState.Key)
                    {
                        case "Property1":
                            apiResponse.ResponseCode = "01";
                            apiResponse.Errors.Add(modelState.Key, modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage).ToList());
                            break;
                        case "Property2":
                            apiResponse.ResponseCode = "02";
                            apiResponse.Errors.Add(modelState.Key, modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage).ToList());
                            break;
                        case "Property3":
                            apiResponse.ResponseCode = "03";
                            apiResponse.Errors.Add(modelState.Key, modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage).ToList());
                            break;
                    }

                    break;
                }

            }
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(apiResponse);
        }

        if (apiResponse.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(apiResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

So for example, for `Property1` if there is any validation error, it should return with code `O1`.

**Edit:**

As suggested by @Max in comment, I have tried by adding `services.AddMvc(options => {                 options.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestModelValidationAttribute )); });`. and then I have observed that `OnActionExecuting` method getas called only when validation is successfull otherwise its not called. So there should be some other work around to solve this problem.

Thank you @Max for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi, did you add inside your startup class `services.AddMvc(options =>
{             
   options.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestModelValidationAttribute ));
});` to add your filter globally ??

Comment: @Max please check my updated question after **Edit**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55735094/8404545) response and in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2) if the controller has [ApiController] it will automatically respond a 400. If you want to disable that you need to suppress that behavior by adding

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        });
```

to you startup class. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#disable-automatic-400-response)
Then your filter will be called.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you Max, Your answer helped me to solve the issue and explorer more. Here is a link of my answer of the exact solution I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120629/6527049