# Best way to implement the ProblemDetails in Asp.Net Core API in clean way

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I need to use [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for the validation errors. It's working as expected. But there is a big problem here, I have to write a similar code in all the action methods and I think it's not a good idea.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<SampleResponse>> Post([FromBody] SampleRequest getRateApiRequest)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            ProblemDetails problemDetails = new ProblemDetails();
            problemDetails.Detail = "Detail";
            problemDetails.Instance = "Instance";
            problemDetails.Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            problemDetails.Title = "Title";
            problemDetails.Type = "Type";

            List<FieldCodeMessage> codeMessages = new List<FieldCodeMessage>();
            foreach (var modelState in ModelState)
            {
                if (modelState.Value.ValidationState == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Invalid)
                {
                    MemberInfo property = typeof(TradeBookingRequestAPI).GetProperty(modelState.Key);
                    var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().Single();
                    string displayName = attribute.DisplayName;
                    switch (modelState.Key)
                    {
                        case "Property1":
                            codeMessages.Add(new FieldCodeMessage(field: displayName, code: "01", message: modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault()));
                            break;
                        case "Property2":
                            codeMessages.Add(new FieldCodeMessage(field: displayName, code: "02", message: modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault()));
                            break;
                        case "Property3":
                            codeMessages.Add(new FieldCodeMessage(field: displayName, code: "03", message: modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault()));
                            break;
                        case "Property4":
                            codeMessages.Add(new FieldCodeMessage(field: displayName, code: "04", message: modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault()));
                            break;
                        case "Property5":
                            codeMessages.Add(new FieldCodeMessage(field: displayName, code: "05", message: modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault()));
                            break;
                        case "Property6":
                            codeMessages.Add(new FieldCodeMessage(field: displayName, code: "06", message: modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault()));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            problemDetails.Extensions.Add("Invalid Fields", codeMessages);

            return BadRequest(problemDetails);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So Is there a way to handle this in a centralized place like middleware or something else.

**Expected response:**

```
{
    "type": "Type",
    "title": "Title",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Detail",
    "instance": "Instance",
    "Invalid Fields": [
        {
            "field": "Proprty 1",
            "code": "01",
            "message": "Invalid Proprty 1"
        },
        {
            "field": "Property 2",
            "code": "02",
            "message": "Invalid Property 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have extened `ValidationAttribute` to implement the validation logic for all properties, Below is implementation for `Property1`.

```
protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    try
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            propertyDisplayName = validationContext.DisplayName;
            long property1 = (Int64)value;
            Match match = Regex.Match($"{property1}", @"^\d+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace($"{property1}") && match.Success)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult($"Invalid {propertyDisplayName}");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"Invalid {propertyDisplayName}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If there is a way to handle this scenario in the extended `ValidationAttribute` classes also, that will also work for me.

**Note:** Target framework is .Net5

Comment: Hi @vivek nuna, I think you can try to custom class which extends `ValidationProblemDetails`. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67916802/11398810

Comment: @Rena Yes, I have tried to use a similar workaround. I will post once it's completed. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Rena I have added my answer, please review and give your feedback :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could able to solve the issue by using the below code in `ConfigureServices` method of Startup.cs.

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest).ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = c =>
    {
        ProblemDetails problemDetails = new ProblemDetails();
        problemDetails.Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
        problemDetails.Title = "One or more validation errors occurred.";
        problemDetails.Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1";
        
        List<FieldCodeMessage> codeMessages = new List<FieldCodeMessage>();
        foreach (var modelState in c.ModelState)
        {
            if (modelState.Value.ValidationState == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Invalid)
            {
                string[] errorMessageCode = modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault().Split(':');
                string code = errorMessageCode[0];
                string message = errorMessageCode[1];

                codeMessages.Add(new FieldCodeMessage(field: modelState.Key, code: code, message: message));
            }
        }

        problemDetails.Extensions.Add("Invalid Fields", codeMessages);

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails);
    };
});
```

I had to use one trick to pass the error code along with the message by using the `:` delimiter like this in `IsValid` method of the extended `ValidationAttribute`.

```
return new ValidationResult("01:Proprty 1");
```

If anyone has a better approach or suggestions, please add a comment. I would be happy to know.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it before for use with jquery unobtrusive validation, but you could adapt it to build a ProblemDetails object via a shared method or extension method pretty easily:

```cs
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var errorMessages = ModelState.GetErrors();

    return Json(new { success = false, errors = errorMessages });
}
```

And ModelState.GetErrors() is a simple extension method:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Converts a Controller's ModelState errors to a Dictionary suitable for consumption clientside by the jquery unobtrusive validation library
/// </summary>
/// <param name="modelState"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> GetErrors(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    return modelState
            .Where(x => x.Value!.Errors.Any())
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value!.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
}
```